# Tabris.js facebook and twitter login

Tags: javascript, tabris

I think tabrisjs is looking like a very good native solution for javascript developers. I am investigating this framework now. But I could not find any details for social login solution for tabris.js
Is tabrisjs supportting facebookSDK for ios and android?
Or do we need to implement a workaround for these kind of features?

Answer (score 3):

tabris.js supports cordova plugins. So, you can simply use the the social plugins like the one from oauth.io and so on. Just go to the documentation and read the cordova guide on tabrisjs.com